# Número incremental por número de cliente en la misma tabla

Tags: c#, sql-server

como podría hacer para tener una tabla con un código de cliente y un consecutivo para cada uno que comienza en 1 y que pueda generar siempre registros nuevos tomando el ultimo consecutivo sin problema de sincronización.

Por ejemplo para generar facturas y con 100 requests simultaneos y que el sistema pueda determinar el ultimo elemento real.

El sistema es en C#.

Esto se puede resolver en SQL Server? O debe ser en C#?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Actualización:***

Comprendo lo que indican, lo del ID autonumerico si lo comprendo y casi todas las tablas lo deben incluir. Pero en este caso. Actualizo el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es tratar de llevar sincronizado el campo **Consecutivo** conforme el numero de cliente. Cada cliente distinto comienza el consecutivo en 1, cuando se agrega un registro la idea es mantener el consecutivo y ante eventuales llamados asincronos que los consecutivos se reserven de manera que no trate de guardar el mismo consecutivo. Espero explicarme correctamente.

Comment: Al momento de guardar el registro en bd puedes hacerlo mediante una secuencia, esta secuencia puede ser sólo numérica o puedes asociarla a un trigger que tenga por inicio lo que tu desees.

Comment: En cuanto a facturación no deberías manejar el numero de factura de esa forma, sino incremental como te marca en la respuesta (por una cuestión legal). Pero si quieres manejarlo de esa forma deberías traer el ultimo id del cliente y ahí le sumas uno.

Comment: Comprendo Ramiro, lo que sucede es que cada cliente tiene su propio consecutivo por decirlo así. Cada uno comenzando desde 1 siempre, ya que la idea es manejar varios clientes con sus propios consecutivos.

Comment: Entonces tenes que hacer una consulta, para traer tu ultimo id antes de insertar.

Comment: Este problema puede ser muy complicado cuando se toma en cuenta la concurrencia de usuarios. Son varios puntos los que hay que tomar en cuenta o terminarás con números duplicados.

Comment: @futurearnold chequeá la edición de mi respuesta por si te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Ni identity, ni las secuencias garantizan la consecutividad de los números.

[Propiedad identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Secuence](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Ambas tienen los mismos problemas. Si se utilizan con una cache, que viene establecida por defecto, en caso de que el servidor se bloquee, o reinicie, se saltan 1000 números.
Además si una transacción no se confirma, poque se hace un rollback, el identity y la secuencia ya han generado el número que nunca se persiste, por tanto te quedarán saltos.

En c# para 100 request simultaneas, veo muy pero que muy dificil, que lo puedas hacer.

En sql server existen técnicas parar realizar esto, pero uno de los puntos prioritarios, es que no dispondrás del número de factura hasta que se haya grabado el mismo.

Puedes mirar este artículo y con unos pequeños retoques utilizando una tabla auxiliar, para conseguir tu objetivo.

[id Incremental](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/23/id-incremental-como/)

Answer (score 1):

Debido a tu pedido yo lo solucionaría con esta consulta antes de guardar un nuevo registro.

```
select MAX(f.Factura) from tbl_Facturas f where f.cod_cliente = 'TuCodigoCliente'
```

Luego incrementas la variable que guardas la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo que querés hacer, deberías setear el campo de la tabla como identity. Esto hace que no tengas que insertarlo, el motor de base de datos solo lo va a calcular.

Esto es parte de la definición de la tabla (Deberías agregarlo con un alter table, o dropeando la tabla y volviendola a crear, siempre exportando los datos) y toma dos parámetros:
**seed** e **incremento**, siendo seed el valor inicial e incremento siendo el valor por el cual se va a ir sumando, y se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]
```

Te adjunto la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15

Lo único que tenes que tener en cuenta es que ante ciertas circunstancias, como inserts fallidos por ejemplo, el identity va a aumentar aunque no se hayan insertado datos, por lo que vas a tener un salto numérico.

Si esto último es problema, lo mas sencillo antes de insertar es traer el último dato e insertar el que corresponda, bloqueando la tabla.

Y te agrego un ejemplo sencillo, en donde el campo comienza en 1 y va incrementando de a 1:

```
create table Sedes
(
    id bigint not null primary key identity (1,1),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    idLocalidad bigint not null foreign key (idLocalidad) references Localidades(id),
    direccion varchar(100) not null,
    telefono int null check (telefono > 0),
    mail varchar(100) null,
    unique (idLocalidad, direccion)
);
```

---

Revisando tu actualización, entiendo que la mejor forma de avanzar, ya que requerís que necesariamente el ID de cliente aumente de manera consecutiva sin saltos (El identity no te serviría), creo la mejor manera de avanzar sería mediante un trigger instead of insert sobre tu tabla, para obtener el ID correcto, donde reemplazarias el id que estas insertando por el que calculas del ultimo

```
create trigger TR_GetLastID
on TablaDondeLoNecesites
after insert
as
begin
        declare @codCliente bigint
        select @codCliente = max(inserted.codCliente) from inserted

        insert into TablaDondeLoNecesites (codCliente + 1, demásDatos...)
end
GO
```

Comment: Creo que no entendiste bien, necesita tener un número secuencial por cada cliente, no reiniciar el identity.

Comment: @LuisCazares nunca hablé de reiniciarlo, si no que le indiqué agregar el identity, que claramente no lo tiene, al campo que lo desea.

Comment: @LuisCazares, correcto en todo caso la tabla si incluiría el ID. Sería el ID, ClienteId, NumeroAutoIncrementable

Answer (score 0):

Puedes apoyarte con una tabla auxiliar y actualizar el consecutivo por medio de un trigger. Adicionalmente puedes manejar algún tipo de restricción (en este caso primary key) para el consecutivo o simplemente realizar la validación en el trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE Factura(Cliente       varchar(20), 
                     Consecutivo   int not null default 0,
                     CONSTRAINT pkFactura PRIMARY KEY(Cliente, Consecutivo))
GO
CREATE TABLE FacturaAux(Cliente                varchar(20), 
                        UltimoConsecutivo      int,
                        CONSTRAINT pkFacturaAux PRIMARY KEY(Cliente))
GO


CREATE TRIGGER TrFactura
ON Factura
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FacturaAux A JOIN inserted B ON A.Cliente = B.Cliente)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT FacturaAux(Cliente, UltimoConsecutivo) SELECT Cliente, 0 FROM inserted 
                END

            UPDATE C SET C.Consecutivo = isnull(B.UltimoConsecutivo,0) + 1 FROM inserted A JOIN FacturaAux B ON A.Cliente = B.Cliente JOIN Factura C ON A.Cliente = C.Cliente AND A.Consecutivo = C.Consecutivo
            UPDATE A SET A.UltimoConsecutivo = isnull(A.UltimoConsecutivo,0) + 1 FROM FacturaAux A JOIN inserted B ON A.Cliente = B.Cliente
        END
END
GO

INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE1');
INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE2');
INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE3');
INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE1');
INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE1');
INSERT Factura(Cliente) VALUES('CTE2');

SELECT * FROM Factura;
SELECT * FROM FacturaAux;

INSERT Factura(Cliente, Consecutivo) VALUES('CTE1', 3);
```